# Ubuntu OpenStack Single Installer - how to install & use the new LXD plugin for Nova

Tags: openstack, lxd

I am aware that there is a new LXD plug-in for Nova to allow OpenStack to create/manage LXC containers using LXD.

I have been using the Ubuntu Single Installer for OpenStack and have it running on a server.    I'd like to know if LXD is or will be supported on this type of installation?

thanks
brian

Answer (score 0):

It will be supported eventually, but isn't yet. As far as I'm aware, only the OpenStack JuJu charms manually deployed are currently LXD-aware.

Both the OpenStack autopilot (landscape) and the openstack cloud installer will grow LXD support for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.